# Create variable of grouped divs from ajax response

Tags: jquery, ajax, find

Okay, this is confusing the hell outta me.

I am making an ajax call to a get_post.php page.  On that page I am creating html from various arrays.  If I were to view the source of this get_post.php page, I would see just basic html, unstylized.

So in my ajax response I am getting just html, which is what I need. Now comes where I am having an issue.

On the get_post.php page I have various divs.

```
<div class="pictures">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="text">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="video">this div has inner elements</div>
```

I will have MANY of each type of div.  I could have 10 div's with the class pictures, 10 with class video and 200 with text.  Each of these divs are a wrapper for inner content. But each are stylized according to their content.

My plan is, when the ajax is success to store all the div types to a variable.

```
var pictures = <div class="pictures">this div has inner elements</div><div class="pictures">this div has inner elements</div><div class="pictures">this div has inner elements</div> etc etc

var text = <div class="text">this div has inner elements</div><div class="text">this div has inner elements</div><div class="text">this div has inner elements</div> etc etc

var videos = <div class="video">this div has inner elements</div><div class="video">this div has inner elements</div><div class="video">this div has inner elements</div> etc etc
```

I need all the divs in a variable so when on an on click I can append them to a list.

```
$('.textLink').click(function() {
$(html).append(text);
});
```

This would append all the divs of text to the end.

What I am having trouble doing is setting these variables of all the div's and their inner content.  How can I do this?

Here is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'interactions/get_posts.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(results) {
        var data = results.responseText;
        var pictures = ????
        var text = ????
        var videos = ????

    },
    error: function(results) {

    }
});
```

and what my ajax response might look like

```
    <div class="pictures">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="text">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="pictures">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="video">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="video">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="pictures">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="video">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="pictures">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="text">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="pictures">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="video">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="pictures">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="text">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="text">this div has inner elements</div>
<div class="text">this div has inner elements</div>
```

I feel like this can be easily done, but I've been going around in loops for so long I am stuck...

Comment: You use `dataType: 'json'` in your ajax call but then you say you're receiving results in html..

Comment: I copied what I am receiving in my console log...